# How to convert multiple rows into a single stacked column in excel?

Tags: excel, format

I'm very new to using excel and have been browsing the answers for similar questions. I have only used the data.table package to convert it into a column as well as a complicated excel formula: 
`=INDEX( $RANGE$ ,INT((ROW()-ROW( $CELL$ ))/COLUMNS( $RANGE$ ))+1,MOD(ROW()-ROW( $CELL$ ),COLUMNS( $RANGE$ ))+1)`.
I was experiencing errors using this excel formula (it told me I needed an extra comma somewhere). 
This is how my data looks now:
[image: Input data]

This is how I want it to look (so I can use it in R): 
[image: Output data]

I have multiple rows of data that need to be converted into one stacked column. Is there a formula in excel or R that can do this?

Comment: Please include your data as [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, your Output data example has the parameters height and area, but your Input data does not have any height or area data. To answer your root question, I would recommend looking at [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/), particularly the `gather` and `spread` functions.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and for pointing that out. I have edited my question so it can hopefully be more useful to others

Comment: Looks like an Unpivot operation that can be done pretty simply in `Power Query`, available in Excel 2010 or later.